# How to conditionally import file in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have have a large application that monitors a file called routes.js . I can not change the file name or mess with routes.js at all. I need to load another file based on a useState variable from another component when a condition is met. This following code will need to be put in Apps.js  example:

```
if (!change) {
import routes from "routes";
} else {
import routes from "newroutes"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Or you can import them both, just *alias* them. The names don't have to be the same ...

Comment: the names have to be the same because the routes variable is monitored. that is the only reason i need this solution

Comment: The "imports" don't have to be the same name. Then you can just declare a `routes` variable and assign to it the appropriate value.

Comment: Can you show where you are calling this code? And explain the use case a little more

Comment: I don't know why i did not think of that . Thank you so much. I have to think of the simplest answer is normally the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just *alias* the imports.

```
import routes_1 from "routes";
import routes_2 from "newroutes"
```

Then, you can just declare a variable: `routes` and assign the appropriate value to it.

```
routes = !change ? routes_1 : routes_2;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to do using [Webpack lazy loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) (if you build your app using Webpack):

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "routes" */ './routes').then(module => {
     const routes = module.default;
});
```

But probably you will need to adjust your build config. Also this import is returning a promise, so you should write your code in the callback.

**Update**: but in your case it seems you don't need it. You could do something like this:

```
import file1 from 'routes'
import file2 from 'newroutes'

let routes = file1
if (change) {
  routes = file2
}
```

So you will have your `routes` variable unchanged